# RxJS Observable.combineLatest never completes

Tags: javascript, rxjs

One of my `Observable.combineLatest` never completes because one of its observables never gets to emit a value, so the completion function is never reached.

Is there a way so I can set a kind of a `timeOut` so after it I can provide a default value for it? or at least a way to tell which observable is not emiting any data at all?

Something like

```js
Observable.combineLatest(...).onTimeOut(() => console.log('No data from 3th observable')
```

Edit:

So given this:

```js
Observable.combineLatest(
  observable1, // <- ok
  observable2, // <- ok
  observable3, // <- timeout
  observable4, // <- ok
  observable5, // <- ok
  (...args) => ({...args})
)
.pipe(
  timeout(1*1000),
  catchError((e) => {
    console.log(e)
    return Observable.of({})
  })
)
.subscribe(() => {})
```

How can I tell that observable3 was the responsible of the timeout?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [timeout](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/timeout) and [catchError](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/catchError) operator (or just [timeoutWith](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/timeoutWith), see edit below) for this use case:

```
combineLatest(...).pipe(
  timeout(myTimeoutValueInMilliseconds),
  // Catch the error thrown by the timeout and return a default value instead.
  catchError(() => of('my default value'))
).subscribe(e => console.log(e))
```

Of course if you need the timeout on only one of the Observables then you can restructure it as follows:

```
combineLatest(
   myObsOne.pipe(
    timeout(myTimeoutValueInMilliseconds),
    catchError(() => of('my default value'))
  ),
  myObsTwo
).subscribe(e => console.log(e))
```

## Edit

As pointed out by Oles Savluk in the comments, you can simplify this solution by using [timoutWith](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/timeoutWith) instead of `timeout` and `catchError`:

```
combineLatest(
   myObsOne.pipe(
    timeoutWith(myTimeoutValueInMilliseconds, of('my default value')),
  ),
  myObsTwo
).subscribe(e => console.log(e))
```

Comment: there also  [timeoutWith](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/timeoutWith) which does exactly same but shorter

Comment: Thanks @OlesSavluk, I have included your feedback! :)

Comment: Thanks @SamHerrmann, as you say now I get at least a Timeout error, however I can't tell which of the observables provoked it unless I add the pipe to each one of the Observables. In my case, at least the index in the arguments list of combineLatest where the timeouted observable was would be very helpful for debugging purpose.

Comment: I think the problem of having default value is covered. I edited question to add extra context for the second problem: to know which observer gave the timeout without having to refactor every observable.